# OS X Cocoa Swift: Setting up a ViewController programmatically (without Storyboard or nib files)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am currently trying to rebuild an existing project in a purely programmatic way (without storyboard and nib files). I know that there are already some posts about that, but they didn't really helped me. This is a way to solve it:

main.swift

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NS Application.shared().delegate = delegate

let ret = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)`
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

   let viewController = ViewController()
   let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSScreen.main()!.frame.size.width, NSScreen.main()!.frame.size.height), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false)

   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
       viewController.view = NSView(NSMakeRect(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height))
       viewController.view.wantsLayer = true
       window.contentView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
       window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
   }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        let button = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 300, height: 30))
        button.action = #selector(ViewController.buttonPressed(_:))
        button.target = self
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonPressed(_: Any?) {
        print("OK")
    }

}
```

Later, the plan is to switch with these buttons between different View Controllers and show different Views. Is this the right way at all or is there a "better" way to do this? My goal is to have one window and different ViewControllers. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the `target` on the button. The `action` tells it which method to call, but without a target it has nothing to call the method on.

You may also need to change your action method to allow for the `sender` parameter: `func buttonPressed(_: Any?) {...}` and set the action to `#selector(ViewController.buttonPressed(_:))`.

I also just noticed that your view controller is only being held in a local variable in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. It should be a property of the `AppDelegate` so that there is a reference to it, otherwise it will get deleted right away.

Comment: Try adding a parameter to your action method. Seed the edited answer.

Comment: when I press the button it creates an error in "let ret = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)" in the main.swift file.. I assume that there might be something wrong with calling the view controller, but i don't know exactly what..

Comment: What kind of error does it create? Is it a crash, or an uncaught exception?

Comment: OK, that's a crash. It may be because the view controller is being deleted.

Comment: okey..do you have any suggestions how to solve it? How does one correctly call a View Controller programmatically in the AppDelegate?

Comment: You're calling it correctly, you just need to store it somewhere outside the function. I'd recommend moving the `let viewController = ViewController()` line outside the function to the class level.

Comment: If that fixes the crash that happened when you clicked the button, then it should be working now. Have you set a breakpoint in `buttonPressed`? Maybe you're looking in the wrong place for the "OK" message.

Comment: You're welcome! One more little thing - it's better to put the `let viewController` (and `window` too) inside the `ViewController` class (still outside the functions) because that's the object that's supposed to own them.

Comment: mhm and how do i call it in the app delegate when not setting there?

Comment: If you just move those lines inside the class, then the view controller and window will get created when the `AppController` is initialized.

Comment: mhm okey now I am little confused..how would the app delegate class and the view controller class would like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. All you need to do is move those two lines inside the class.

Comment: yeah but how do I call the code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method?

Comment: It gets called automatically. You're already setting the application delegate, so `NSApplicationMain` starts the app, which calls `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: I am really sorry but can you please show me how those two classes would look like, because I am absolutely not sure what you mean..

Comment: Same as what you have now, except `let viewController` and `let window` go right before `func applicationDidFinishLaunching()`.

Comment: yeah but then I get an error message in the applicationDidFinishLaunching() method because I use unresolved identifiers..

Comment: I don't know why that would be... and pasting the code in comments would be too big.

Comment: what would be inside the applicationsDidFinishLaunching() method? the same as now? I cannot access a variable viewController when it's not defined..

Comment: `applicationsDidFinishLaunching` doesn't need to change. Like this: https://gist.github.com/Uncommon/ca36550bdc4e9db606e70fc2f2e1223b

Comment: but there is the view controller and the window initialised on class level?

Comment: Yes, they will get initialized when the app delegate is created.

Comment: yes, so what did you mean with:  
You're welcome! One more little thing - it's better to put the let viewController (and window too) inside the ViewController class (still outside the functions) because that's the object that's supposed to own them.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the app delegate class. Is that why you were confused?

Comment: aaaah yeah that really confused me.. so the way it is like in my updated question is the "correct" way you would do it too?

Comment: I don't see a new update. It's all fine except I would do AppDelegate like in the gist link above.